# Var Already defined in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I'm brand new to AMPL and can't seem to get past this issue.
The code I've written is very basic (again, just starting out) but I keep getting this error message "AMPLPrac.mod, line 2 (offset 6):
x1 is already defined
context:  var  >>> x1> <<< =0;"

Here is the code:

```
var x1>=0; var x2>=0;

maximize z: 2*x1 + 3*x2;

subject to c1: 2*x1 + x2 <=4; c2: x1 + 2*x2 <=5;

solve;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help! It turns out that the other issues I was having was that I had downloaded not the full version of AMPL and didn't have the correct solvers installed too so I was also getting error messages about not having Minos installed etc but it seems to be resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are defining to variables on the same line i AMPL. I tried to run this code (who is the same as yours, only with one argument at every line:

```
var x1 >= 0;
var x2 >= 0;

maximize z: 2*x1 + 3*x2;
subject to c1: 2 * x1 + x2 <= 4;
subject to c2: x1 + 2 * x2 <= 5;
```

And I got no errors, and the following output:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
```

So I think the problem must be that you have defines mulitply variables on the same line. So to next time, just one variables in every line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by **eriksen1110** is correct, but the problem with your model is that you omited the multiplication operator `*` from your math expressions, which is not possible in AMPL. It should be:

```
maximize z: 2*x1 + 3*x2;
#            ^      ^
subject to c1: 2*x1 + x2 <= 4;
#               ^
subject to c2: x1 + 2*x2 <= 5;
#                    ^
```

[See it on PIFOP](https://pifop.com/app?view=ebwjRKZE0gHlwKPa62zu&open=fcxkhKZ7STPVIZ5k0ba1&active=fcxkhKZ7STPVIZ5k0ba1)

However, you said that AMPL reports that x1 is already defined, which makes me suspect that you are reading the model file twice, and thus declaring the variable twice, which cannot be done.

Try reseting all declarations by putting this at the beggining of your model file:

```
reset;
```